# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'num'

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i just recently tring to work our my barhcart using synchfusion package, when i working with the barchart it appear that my subtype is not a num, where i didnt think that i have declared my list as num except for the chartData number

```
import 'dart:ffi';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class barchart_new extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _barchart_newState createState() => _barchart_newState();
}

class _barchart_newState extends State<barchart_new> {
  final List<SalesData> chartData = [
    SalesData('Driving', 35, 23),
    SalesData('Office work', 38, 49),
    SalesData('meeting', 34, 12),
    SalesData('onsite work', 52, 33),
    SalesData('seminar', 40, 30)
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(series: <ChartSeries>[
      BarSeries<SalesData, String>(
          dataSource: chartData,
          xValueMapper: (SalesData year, _) => year.year,
          yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)))
    ]))));
  }
}

class SalesData {
  SalesData(this.year, this.sales, this.colors);
  final String year;
  final double sales;
  final double colors;
}
```

really appreciate if anyone can help me out to rectify this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
// import 'dart:ffi'; delete this line. you are probebly not using ffi.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';

class barchart_new extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _barchart_newState createState() => _barchart_newState();
}

class _barchart_newState extends State<barchart_new> {
  final List<SalesData> chartData = [
    SalesData('Driving', 35, 23),
    SalesData('Office work', 38, 49),
    SalesData('meeting', 34, 12),
    SalesData('onsite work', 52, 33),
    SalesData('seminar', 40, 30)
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Container(
                child: SfCartesianChart(series: <ChartSeries>[
      BarSeries<SalesData, String>(
          dataSource: chartData,
          // your year is a string. convert it using the `int.tryParse` function
          xValueMapper: (SalesData year, _) => int.tryParse(year.year),
          yValueMapper: (SalesData sales, _) => sales.sales,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15)))
    ]))));
  }
}

class SalesData {
  SalesData(this.year, this.sales, this.colors);
  final String year;
  final double sales;
  final double colors;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else who gets this error and actually wants a String value on the X Axis, you can try to specify the primaryXAxis as a CategoryAxis:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // For horizontal bar charts, set the [vertical] flag to false.
    return new SfCartesianChart(
      series: _createSeriesFromData(),
      primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
        majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      ),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
          majorGridLines: MajorGridLines(width: 0),
          numberFormat: NumberFormat.compact()),
    );
  }
```